# How to solve "The return type 'DocumentReference ()' isn't a 'DocumentReference ()', as defined by the method" error?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have 3 functions, `doesNameAlreadyExist` checks whether a document is exists or not. **I'm open to any improvement on those methods by the way.**

```
   Future<bool> doesNameAlreadyExist(String name) async {

      QuerySnapshot queryDb = await Firestore.instance
          .collection('locations')
          .where("city", isEqualTo: '${name}')
          .limit(1)
          .getDocuments();
      final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = queryDb.documents;
      return documents.length == 1;
// I have to return DocumentReference if document is exists,
// Even though, it's not on the scope of this particular problem,
// I'm open to ideas. Maybe I can return a map, bool and reference combined


    }
```

This one pushes document on firestore.

```
    Future<DocumentReference> pushNameToFirestore(PlaceDetails pd) async {

      Future<DocumentReference> justAddedRef = Firestore.instance.collection('locations').add(<String, String>{
        'city': '${pd.name}',
        'image': '${buildPhotoURL(pd.photos[0].photoReference)}',
      });
      return justAddedRef;
    }
```

And here, I'm checking and then pushing with those functions above. However I can't return the document reference.

```
    DocumentReference firestoreCheckAndPush() async {
     bool nameExists =  await doesNameAlreadyExist(placeDetail.name);
     // TODO notify user with snackbar and return reference
     DocumentReference locationDocumentRef;
     if(nameExists) {
       print('name exist');
     } else {
         locationDocumentRef = await pushNameToFirestore(placeDetail);
     }
        return locationDocumentRef; // Error is here
    }
```

Comment: If it's an async method, the return type should be `Future<DocumentReference>`. That is probably the issue.

Comment: Also, this line `final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = queryDb.documents;` seems redundant, unless you're planning on using the documents reference somewhere. You can simple return `queryDb.documents == 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you don't wait for your `DocumentReference`, so you return a `Future` instead of a `DocumentReference` which is actually expected.

Try this:

```
    Future<DocumentReference> pushNameToFirestore(PlaceDetails pd) async {

      DocumentReference justAddedRef = await Firestore.instance.collection('locations').add(<String, String>{
        'city': '${pd.name}',
        'image': '${buildPhotoURL(pd.photos[0].photoReference)}',
      });
      return justAddedRef;
    }
```

Here's a great article about future and async : [Link to the article](https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/01/futures---isolates---event-loop/)

Hope it's help !!